# There's an undesired space appears when using 'float'

Tags: html, css, css-float

When using `float` appears an undesired space at the first line.

```css
div#showCode_container {
  float: left;
  font: bold 14px arial;
}

#editor {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: mediumblue;
}

#lineNumber {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  float: left;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ff9000;
}

#codeArea {
  min-height: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#codeArea:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="showCode_container">
  <h3> Show the code: </h3>
  <div id="editor">
    <div id="lineNumber">1<br/>2<br/>3</div>
    <pre id="codeArea">A text</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

An additional screenshot from my computer:

[image]

**Why that space appeared, and how to resolve that problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The float is adding a margin to the top. If you add `margin-top:0px` it will remove the space. Your particular situation has to do with [collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

```css
div#showCode_container {
  float: left;
  font: bold 14px arial;
}

#editor {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: mediumblue;
}

#lineNumber {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  float: left;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ff9000;
}

#codeArea {
  min-height: 500px;
  float: left;
margin-top:0px;
}

#codeArea:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="showCode_container">
  <h3> Show the code: </h3>
  <div id="editor">
    <div id="lineNumber">1<br/>2<br/>3</div>
    <pre id="codeArea">A text</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a margin of `1em` on the `#codeArea`, applied by the user-agent, which creates the undesired space.  Set `margin-top: 0` to remove it.

```css
div#showCode_container {
  float: left;
  font: bold 14px arial;
}

#editor {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: mediumblue;
}

#lineNumber {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  float: left;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ff9000;
}

#codeArea {
  min-height: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#codeArea:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="showCode_container">
  <h3> Show the code: </h3>
  <div id="editor">
    <div id="lineNumber">1<br/>2<br/>3</div>
    <pre id="codeArea">A text</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```